# Android custom ArrayAdapter | Change icon on ImageView click

Tags: android, listview, imageview, onclicklistener

I have a list with elements that use a custom layout which consists of a text view and an image view. For this, I follow ViewHolder pattern like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230628). The image views display one of two icons and I want to change the icon of the clicked image view.

So my first approach was to define the on click listener of the ImageViews in the overridden *getView* function of my adapter class. The problem is that when the icon of the first ImageView changes and I scroll down to the last its icon changed as well. [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437851/custom-arrayadapterobject-viewholder-imageview-changes-for-several-items-in) was not helpful.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40420379/8082357) I found that it's not the best way to handle the click in the *getView* function but it's better to do it in the *listView.setOnItemClickListener*. I tried it but I am not able to find out whether an ImageView was clicked or not as the *parent* object holds the list item and the *view* parameter the LinearLayout in which the ImageView is contained (even when I click directly in the ImageView). Setting `android:focusable="false"` of the outer LinearLayout as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17805171/8082357) did not help.

I'm sure someone must have had this issue / use case but I'm not able to find a solution. So, what's the best way to handle the click of the ImageView in my custon list item view?

Comment: when you click in the imageview you should have the second icon.what if you clicked again, the first icon appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following attributes to the clickable ImageView instead of its ViewGroup, your LinearLayout:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

... and as far as updating UI in a AdapterView/ListView/RecyclerView goes, you should make good use of an int flag that tracks the position of the list item that was clicked, and then set it as a conditional statement in `getView()` before invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()`, since "every other" row will be updated, especially in lists of say, 100 rows.

I actually answered this in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574841/5385758) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867393/5385758).

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. As a matter of fact, the values _focusable_ and _focusableInTouchMode_ did not make a difference. I created a private variable in my `Adapter` class which stores the position of the image with the pause icon. In the `draw` method I distinguished between the cases where position of the `draw` method equals the position of the pause icon to set the correct icon. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16453443) I found some advice where to assign the `OnClickListener` to have good performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two icons, you can simply put a custom checkbox instead of an imageview :

```
<CheckBox

            android:id="@+id/customchechecbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"  />


checkbox_selector :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxselected" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>    
</selector>
```

Comment: I see the point of your approach but regard it as a "tricky workaround" which is why I followed @DaveNOTDavid's advice.